# Excel Cell styling

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I want to get a full styling in Excel sheet's cells like merging, coloring and font sizing. Now I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library for this but I am getting confused to use it.

this is code that I am using for now

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            excelApp.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
            excelApp.Columns.ColumnWidth = 20;
            excelApp.Cells[7, 1].Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = 1d;
```

I also want to make merging cell, style border and coloring too.Can somebody help to with an example code please??

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401996/microsoft-interop-excel-formatting-cells

Comment: Sorry sir I again I have same problems :(

Comment: Try recording a macro in excel while applying the styling you want: that will guide you on where to look in Interop.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks who try to solve my problem and I found this solution for my own question problem

```
            // what is here merging    
            excelApp.Range[excelApp.Cells[2, 2], excelApp.Cells[2, 5]].Merge();

            // what is here boarder
            excelApp.Range[excelApp.Cells[1, 1], excelApp.Cells[1, 2]].Borders[Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlBordersIndex.xlEdgeLeft].Weight = 3d;
```