# How to add xml schema/design file to Excel Interop?

Tags: c#, xml, excel, winforms, office-interop

I am creating an excel file using a data table in excel interop

```
Price           Profit/Loss%

250.8982989       0.04301071
```

I have a schema file which has details for design as 
1) make all headers bold
2) column definition (weather,string,percentage)

I used this file in fast report export but as such i have to use interop for excel export is there a way i can add that schema file

```
  Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();

            //Create an Excel workbook instance and open it from the predefined location
            Excel.Workbook excelWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet);


            //Add a new worksheet to workbook with the Datatable name
            Excel.Worksheet excelWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets.Add();


            for (int i = 1; i < table.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
            {
                excelWorkSheet.Cells[1, i] = table.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < table.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int k = 0; k < table.Columns.Count; k++)
                {
                    excelWorkSheet.Cells[j + 2, k + 1] = table.Rows[j].ItemArray[k].ToString();
                }
            }

            excelWorkBook.SaveAs(@"D:\sample excel.xls");
            excelWorkBook.Close();
            excelApp.Quit();
```

i want to show this value in bold and format as % **0.04301071**

make this value Bold and round **250.8982989**

This all information will be stored in a schema file i want to load that file

or else i want to load that cell as per the columns datatype in datatable

I have tried :-

```
clmnrange.NumberFormat = (Object)table.Columns[k - 1].DataType;
```

but it is raising an exception

Regards 
EP

Comment: I have the same problem can anybody suugest a solution

Comment: Can you possibly provide a full blown example (like 2 columns and 2 rows) with schema XML, data and expected outcome? The question is kindof incomplete right now (`table` is not even defined, ...)

Comment: The NumberFormat property takes a string that uses Excel's formatting syntax. For example formatting as a percentage (up to) 8 decimal places is "0.########%". I'm guessing that the "DataType" property you are trying to assign is not a string setup for Excel formatting. I would think that you would need to convert any formatting definitions from the table into methods Excel uses for formatting.

Comment: @Wedge can u show any example of it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [microsoft.interop.excel Formatting cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7401996/microsoft-interop-excel-formatting-cells)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [above comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43627005#comment74416901_43627005):

> The NumberFormat property takes a string that uses Excel's formatting
>   syntax. For example formatting as a percentage (up to) 8 decimal
>   places is "0.########%"

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7872116/applying-number-format-to-a-cell-value-using-openxml) is an example that someone else provided showing how to implement the type of numberingFormat you are describing:

```
WorkbookStylesPart sp = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
```

Create a stylesheet:

```
sp.Stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
```

Create a numberingFormat:

```
sp.Stylesheet.NumberingFormats = new NumberingFormats();
// #.##% is also Excel style index 1

NumberingFormat nf2decimal = new NumberingFormat();
nf2decimal.NumberFormatId = UInt32Value.FromUInt32(3453);
nf2decimal.FormatCode = StringValue.FromString("0.0%");
sp.Stylesheet.NumberingFormat.Append(nf2decimal);
```